# Customizing Core-Plot Iphone graph plot

Tags: iphone, graph, core-plot

I wish to customize the core plot graph library for Iphone a bit.
   I got some nice tutorials on this, for eg: 
  [http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2/)

But, in this tutorial one can draw scatter plot graphs that start with 0, and then we can increment the Y-axis accordingly.

I want the graph to be a very relative one (based on the input).

for eg: If I have 7 points viz:(82,83,84,85,86,87,88).

Then I want a graph that will start from 80(Y-min) and end on 90(Y-max).

Can anyone please help me out in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `yRange` on the plot space. Plot ranges are similar to `NSRange`; you specify the starting location (80) and the length of the range (10).

```
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(80.0)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(10.0)];
```